# Determine the probability density function

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have the following problem. Let's say `g` is a function of `A` and `R`. I run a Monte Carlo analysis to determine the pdf of `g` considering the real pdf of `R` but with `A` having a rectangular pdf. Now I have new information about the pdf of `A`. My question is: Do I need to run my Monte Carlo again or can I apply to my old pdf of `g` the newly available pdf of `A`?

EDIT 1: Both old and new pdfs of `A` share the same minimum and maximum possible values, i.e. both pdfs are bounded by the same lower and upper limits. The difference is that while in the first Monte Carlo run `A` was considered to have a rectangular pdf, now with new information `A` pdf is Gaussian. It can be assumed that `A` and `R` are independent.
Let the old pdf of `A` be a uniform pdf with minimum value equal to a=0 and maximum value equal to b=0.1 and the new pdf of `A` be a truncated Gaussian with equal a and b and an average value of 0.06 and a standard deviation equal to 0.01.

EDIT 2: If `g` was a function of `R`, `A1`, `A2`, ..., `An` and all these random variables were independent is it also possible to update the old pdf of `g` not needing to run Monte Carlo again?

Comment: The answer might depend on precisely how $A$ was changed. If dramatic changes occurred (especially if some values previously considered possible became impossible), it is difficult to imagine how the results could be salvaged, but if the new $A$ could be expressed as a mixture of the old $A$ and another distribution, then it is obvious how to augment the existing results. Could you please therefore edit your question to give us this detail about $A$?

Comment: Thanks.  Specifics would be helpful.  What really matters is the minimum ratio between the new density and the old density (which could get really small for a Gaussian). It tells you roughly what fraction of the old results you can rescue.  If it's small, don't bother.

Comment: @whuber I've just added an example of the old and new pdf of random variable `A`. Thanks

Comment: If you have retained the A values for each simulation, along with the individual g's (which wouldn't be feasible in some applications), there are things that might be done.

Comment: Yes, I have the values of A and of g for every calculation. Thanks